# check if current dir contains spaces in its name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like my script to abort if the current directory contains a space in its name.

My thought was to use `%~s` but so far my efforts are frustrating. The following works, but I don't like it. My attempts at passing a parameter have been futile.

Any suggestion for improvements?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

for /f %%f in ("%cd%") do (
    if NOT "%%f" == "%cd%" (
      echo bad dir"%cd%" contains spaces
    ) else (
      echo no spaces in "%cd%"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Use FINDSTR instead, it allows you to use regex also, or use "tokens and delims" for FOR, http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
if "%CD%"=="%CD: =%" (
  echo no spaces in "%cd%"
) else (
  echo bad dir"%cd%" contains spaces
)
```

Comment: This is so completely wrong...when there are spaces in the current directory it says no spaces and where there are none it says contains spaces...<smile/>. +1

Comment: @MiserableVariable Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.